# Issue with reputation data in Activity tab

Tags: support, reputation

There is some data missing in my [Activity - summary tab](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/28470/arulkumar?tab=summary) **Reputation** section. Since I scored [35](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78011/word-for-a-person-who-increases-the-argument), [10](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79198/how-can-i-ask-a-person-in-which-order-in-his-family-among-the-siblings) reputations from these questions as well +2 reputations for accept the answer for each questions.

But in my reputation section it showing only 2 items. Initially I thought its due to cache, but its not. After clear browser cache and try with different browsers also the same issue exists.

[image: Reputation issue]

Comment: You can click on "Reputation" (the text before "(389)" in your screenshot) to see detail records.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: Yes I can see the detailed report under the Reputation tab, but the Reputation section shows only the recent reputation change? that always last 2 change only?

Comment: I'm not sure how they summarize the records. My best guess would be it's only for recent changes, perhaps only this week.

Comment: @DamkerngT. : I think No. Even currently I scored 275 points from the same question _(it was answered Yesterday)_ and it is showing 230 points only. So not on weekly basis.

Answer (score 2):

The Reputation section shows your reputation change since Jan 8th. The question you're looking at was asked Jan 6th. If someone didn't up-vote your question on Jan 8th or later, it won't show up on the graph or the list below.

The two sections don't match exactly, especially when you have your questions sorted by number of votes. Even if you sort by "activity", that doesn't exactly match "someone has voted on your question and changed your reputation". The reputation section doesn't include reputation changes that you should already know about because it was an action you took that caused them, for example, when you accept an answer or down-vote a post.

Comment: The summary also does not show +2 from accepting an answer.

Comment: @Nathan It's my understanding that it's just reputation changes awarded from other folks (it doesn't show your down votes either), and that if you want to see everything you need to look at the detailed list.